# Enitify Framework code first: Updating Entity With required related navigational property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1, entity-relationship

My model looks like this

```
public Class Address 
{
     public int Id {get;set;}

     /*Props here*/
}

public Class Person
{
     public int Id {get;set;}

     public String Name {get;set;}

     [Required]      
     public Address Address{get;set;}

     /*More props*/
}
```

Now suppose i have created a person  with proper address, in future when i try to update person like this

```
var person= db.Persons.FirstOrDefault(p=>p.Id=1234);
person.Name="Foo";
db.SaveChanges();
```

**It gives error saying Address is required.**

So to avoid  this iam including Address property too while loading Person Entity

```
var person= db.Persons.Include(p=>p.Address).FirstOrDefault(p=>p.Id=1234);
person.Name="Foo";
db.SaveChanges();
```

Is there any way i can update `person` Without including `Address`.

Comment: Does your `Address` entity have a primary key specified (either implicitely with an `Id` property, or explicitely with the `[Key]` attribute)?

Comment: @KallDrexx : yes it has, updated my question

Answer (score 3):

It's the model validation of `DbContext` which complains apparently. So, one solution would be to switch off this validation:

```
dbContext.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
```

The other option is to introduce a foreign key property:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public String Name {get;set;}
    public int AddressId {get;set;}
    public Address Address {get;set;}

    /*More props*/
}
```

You can omit the `[Required]` attribute here because EF will detect the relationship as required by convention (due to the non-nullable FK property). This works also with enabled validation.

The behaviour is a bit confusing since EF doesn't send a change of the FK column to the database, so there is not really a constraint violation and the Update command executes fine. I guess that the validation just checks the state of the model in memory (invalid, because `Address` is null) and not the state the model would have in the database when `SaveChanges` did execute (valid, because FK is correctly set).

Answer (score 0):

If you want the address to be automatically loaded by EF 4.1 you have to make the Address-porperty virtual:

```
public virtual Address Address{get;set;}
```

EF will then lazy-load the address when needed.

Comment: I know this, I dont want it to be lazy loaded. I just dont want it be loaded and while updating Model.

Comment: Sorry, can't help you then. Your model states that "Address" is a required property. If you need to bypass this maybe you should alter your model?

Comment: this definitely resolves problem and A lot more logical than disabling validations.